# Apache POI locks all cells by default. How to make all cells unlocked?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can i make all cells in a sheet unlocked by default?

This snippet creates a sheet with all cells locked

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Results");
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
Cell cell = row.createCell(counter);
cell.setCellValue("test");
```

This snippet causes some corrupt data when trying to open the excel file

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Results");
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
Cell cell = row.createCell(counter);
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setLocked(false);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
cell.setCellValue("test");
```

This snippet doesn't cause any problems, but it also does unlock the cells. I can modify all the cells, but if i click on "format", the "Lock Cells" link is highlighted.

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Results");
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
Cell cell = row.createCell(counter);
cell.setCellValue("test");
cell.getCellStyle().setLocked(false);
```

Comment: Where is your `row` object coming from? (It's not in your code snippet)

Comment: I am not familiar with SXSSFWorkbook, but in the documentation it looks like a "light" implementation of XSSFWorkbook - did you try that?

Comment: I forgot to post my row line. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet **does not** produce a document with locked cells using POI 3.9.

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Results");
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("test");

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Cells are editable in the resulting workbook, as expected.

SXSSF is the streaming POI API. It's optimized for writing huge amounts of data to XML based spreadsheets (the normal XSSF api keeps XML docs in memory and can use huge amounts of memory when building large documents). If you don't need to output large XML based documents, I'd recommend just using the XSSF api as SXSSF has several restrictions and gotchas and isn't as well documented.

See also:

- [SXSSF Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf)
- [POI Quick Start](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)